# How to align multiple (independent) equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

Can I somehow force my equations to all have the equal sign on the horizontal middle axis of the page? The equations are already individually aligned, but I would like to align them globally. I found `\intertext{<text>}` but this is not a good option.

EDIT: An example of code that is locally aligned but not globally.

```
\begin{equation}
F=\mathbb{E}_{Q}[\log Q(\widetilde{\boldsymbol{s}})-\log P(\widetilde{\boldsymbol{s}}, \widetilde{\boldsymbol{o}})]
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
F &=\mathbb{E}_{Q}[\log Q(\tilde{\boldsymbol{s}})-\log P(\widetilde{\boldsymbol{s}}, \widetilde{\boldsymbol{o}})] \\
&=\mathbb{E}_{Q}[\log Q(\widetilde{\boldsymbol{s}})-\log P(\widetilde{\boldsymbol{s}} \mid \widetilde{\boldsymbol{o}})-\log P(\widetilde{\boldsymbol{o}})] \\
&=D_{\mathrm{KL}}(Q(\widetilde{\boldsymbol{s}}) \| P(\widetilde{\boldsymbol{x}} \mid \widetilde{\boldsymbol{o}}))-\log P(\widetilde{\boldsymbol{o}})
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\log (p(x)) &=\mathbb{E}_{z \sim q}[\log (p(x))] \\
&\left.=\mathbb{E}_{z \sim q}\left[\log \left(\frac{p(z, x)}{p(z \mid x)}\right)\right]\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short compilable TeX code we can play with?

Comment: Hi Mensch. Sure, I added some code above to clarify what I would like to do.

Comment: You can give a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/343911/82917.

Comment: Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115534/align-separate-equations, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129369/alternative-to-align-in-this-case?noredirect=1&lq=1, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122069/align-all-equal-signs-in-the-document?noredirect=1&lq=1