# Can't align list of equations uniformly after "subequations" break, why?

Tags: equations, align, subequations

I'm trying to write a list of equations from a chapter of my textbook, each one preceded by a `\label{}` command so that I can refer to it in the rest of the text.

However after the 1st `\begin{align} \end{align}` environment, I've inserted a `\begin{subequations}` environment, then another `\begin{align}` environment. This has resulted in 3 blocks of equations that are aligned each in their own way. I want them to align all as the 1st block of equations. **Is there a way to do that?**

I'm using the `scrartcl` class, a number of packages that I've listed below and some `\newcommand` to speed up the typing. I'm running TeXLive 2013 on Win7 with TeXStudio 2.6.6.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{outlines}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage[italian]{cleveref} % \cref adds ``fig.'' or ``eq.'' before the reference

\graphicspath{{./pictures/}} %{./figuresdir2/}{./figuresdir3/}}

\renewcommand{\@}{\MVAt}
%\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault} %uses sans-serif font for entire document
\newcommand{\domanda}[1]{\paragraph{Q: #1\newline}}
\newcommand{\es}{\varepsilon_s}
\newcommand{\Nd}{N\ped{d}}
\newcommand{\Na}{N\ped{a}} 
\newcommand{\xd}{$x\ped{d}$}
\newcommand{\Ld}{$L\ped{D}$}
\newcommand{\Oi}{$\phi_i$}
\newcommand{\campoE}{\mathscr{E}\ped{x}}
\newcommand{\wf}{$q\Phi$}
\newcommand{\WF}[1]{\Phi_\text{#1}}
\newcommand{\derivata}[2]{\frac{\textup{d}{#1}}{\textup{d}{#2}} }
\newcommand{\derivataseconda}[2]{\frac{\textup{d}^2{#1}}{\textup{d}{#2}^2} }
\newcommand{\derivataparziale}[2]{\dfrac{\partial{#1}}{\partial {#2}} }
\newcommand{\integrale}[4]{\displaystyle \int_{#3}^{#4}#1\,\text{d}{#2} }
\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}
\DeclareMathOperator\erfc{erfc}
\newcommand{\email}[1]{\href{mailto:#1}{{\small\texttt{#1}}}}
%----------------------------------
\title{E.S.S.}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}

\clearpage

\include{cap7}
\include{cap7_formule}
\end{document}
```

This is the `cap7_formule.tex` file, containing the said 3 blocks of equations that I can't get aligned uniformly:

```
\section{Formule cap.7}
\begin{align}
\label{7.1.1} I\ped{c} &=\dfrac{q\tilde{D\ped{n}} n\ped{i}^{2} A\ped{E} \, \exp({qV\ped{BE}/kT})}{\integrale{p}{x}{0}{x_B} } & \\
\label{7.1.2} \derivataparziale{I_C}{V\ped{CB}}&= \dfrac{-q\tilde{D\ped{n}}     n\ped{i}^{2} A\ped{E} \, \exp({qV\ped{BE}/kT}) \, p(x_B) }{\bigg[\integrale{p}{x}{0}{x_B}     \bigg]^{2}} \, \derivataparziale{x_B}{V\ped{CB}}&\\
\label{7.1.3} \notag \derivataparziale{I\ped{C}}{V\ped{CB}}&= -I\ped{C}\,p(x\ped{B})    \Bigg[ \dfrac{1}{\integrale{p}{x}{0}{x\ped{B}}} \Bigg] \, \bigg [\derivataparziale{x\ped{B}}{V\ped{CB}} \bigg] &\\
 &= {} -\dfrac{I\ped{C}}{V\ped{A}}=\dfrac{I_C}{|V_A|}\\
\label{7.1.4} V\ped{A}&= \dfrac{\integrale{p}{x}{0}{x_B} }{p(x\ped{B}) \derivataparziale{x\ped{B}}{V\ped{CB}}}
\end{align}

\begin{subequations}
Scrivo V\ped{A}, la tensione di Early, in modo pratico:
\label{eqn:alternativeVa}
\begin{align}
\label{7.1.5}  \integrale{p}{x}{0}{x\ped{B}}&=\dfrac{Q\ped{B}}{q}\\
\label{7.1.6} q\, p(x\ped{B}) \, \derivata{x_B}{V\ped{CB}}&=\derivata{Q_B}{V\ped{CB}}\\
\label{7.1.7} \bigg| \derivata{Q_B}{V\ped{CB}} \bigg|&= C\ped{jc}\\
\label{7.1.8} |V\ped{A}|&= \dfrac{Q\ped{B}}{C\ped{jC}}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\begin{align}
\label{7.2.1}I_B&= I_0\, \exp\big( {\dfrac{qV\ped{BE}}{nkT}} \big)\\
\label{7.2.2} \integrale{p(x)}{x}{0}{x\ped{B}}&=\integrale{[N\ped{a}(x) + \, n'(x)]}{x}{0}{x\ped{B}}\\
\label{7.2.3} n(0) &=\dfrac{N\ped{a}(0)}{2} \bigg[ \bigg(1+ \dfrac{4 \, n^{2}\ped{i} \, \exp(qV\ped{BE}/kT)}{N\ped{a}(0)} \bigg)^{1/ \,2} -1 \bigg]\\
\label{7.2.4} \derivata{\campoE}{x}&=\dfrac{1}{\varepsilon\ped{s}}\bigg( q\,N(x) - \dfrac{J_C}{v(x)} \bigg)\\
\label{7.2.5}  V\ped{CB}+\phi \ped{i}&=\integrale{-\campoE}{x}{x_B}{x_C}
\end{align}
```

Here is what I get in the pdf:

[image: As you can see, the 3 blocks aren't aligned uniformly]

Comment: Please always post complete small documents not fragments that can not be run locally. However looking at your image the alignment isn't related to the subequation, it is simply that align centres the equation and your second block is smaller so more indented

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80134/nesting-subequations-within-align. See if this is of any help to you.

Comment: @Umz it seems a bit too complicated... I might as well leave things as they are, can't help it, I'm hard up for time to finish this chapter. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122069/align-all-equal-signs-in-the-document/131140#131140 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115534/align-separate-equations/115549#115549